# How to specify TFTP server in DHCP settings?

Tags: windows-server-2012, tftp, polycom

We have a Windows Server 2012 and I want to run a dhcp server on this machine for the network.

In a linux dhcp server I can specify the tftp server and my polycom phones will pick up the directory and know where to fetch their configuration settings.

The tftp server is already running on a machine in the network, and it is this machine that I want to point to.

How do I specify that tftp directory on the Windows Server dhcp server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TFTP server on it's own does not have any reason to exist.
And because of that, there's no such option in DHCP (it's like specifying HTTP server in DHCP. Unless you know what is it for, it's useless).

From what I've read, polycom can download their configuration from HTTP and FTP, not only TFTP.
They use DHCP options 160 and 66 for configuration URL, option type is String.
Opt.66 is only checked if there is no option 160 in DHCP.

Examples of such URL:

```
ftp://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
ftp://username:password@xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
tftp://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
```

I've taken it from correspoding [thread in polycom support forum](http://community.polycom.com/t5/VoIP/Polycom-SoundPoint-IP-331-Option-160-Boot-server-setup-in/td-p/1544).

Just in case, [here is example how to add custom options in DHCP server of Windows Server 2012](http://www.virtuallyimpossible.co.uk/%EF%BB%BFpredefined-dhcp-options-for-voip-on-server-2008-r2/).
Generally, you click RMB in IPv4 node under DHCP in Server Configuration (Server Manager) tree, and select `Set Predefined Options`. You also could set predefined options for ranges and reservations, whichever is more appropriate/convenient for you.

Comment: LogicDaemon has the right answer - thanks!  I found another useful link here: http://help.fonality.com/IP_Phones/Setting_the_Boot_Server